# Cryptographic hash function based on logistic map?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, preimage-resistance, 2nd-preimage-resistance

Is there any secure cryptographic hash function based on the logistic map?

Comment: Unlikely—there's very little, if anything, in cryptography that's inspired by chaotic behavior in continuous systems.

Comment: I found some papers stating things like "Utilizing chaos to construct hash function is a promising direction which attracts more and more attention." Isn't that true?

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-20542-2_5
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/94c2/8f78022333734cd61bbc9c989a6d19344cb4.pdf

Comment: It's not promising. It gets so much unwarranted attention and it is so bad that we joke about it. But we ***really*** wish it wasn't that way. It's a viral idea and it keeps getting reinvented. Academics (usually people who study something in a different field) that promote it likely haven't put significant effort into studying modern cryptography. To use an analogy: These are not chemists, they're members of a school alchemy club. And they don't even realize it because they're not humble enough to consider that there is a huge legitimate body of collective knowledge to base ideas off of.

Comment: @LinusK This is not a serious cryptography paper, and the journal is a paper mill publishing scam to harvest money from aspiring academics in developing countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A brief description of such functions can be found in chapter 9.3 of the paper “Cryptographic Hash Functions: Recent Design Trends and Security Notions” ([eprint.iacr.org/2011/565](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/565)). The following excerpt is taken from page 29 of the paper:

> Hash functions based on chaos theory use *chaotic maps*, which are functions that exhibit particular chaotic behaviours; examples of these maps include: logistic map [[source #75](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253155858_New_hash_function_based_on_chaos_theory_CHA-1)], tent map [[source #120](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3452181_Hash_function_based_on_chaotic_tent_maps)], and cat map [[source #42](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1007570409003426)]. Unfortunately, most chaos-based hash functions suffer from poor efficiency due to their inherent complex structure, which makes them unattractive as a practical approach for building hash functions.